# How to use .html() with a timer in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the contents of a div with the values found in an array. I want to keep each value within the div for 3 seconds each. Here's my code so far:

```
        var images = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'];

        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          $('#slideShow').html("<img src='../"+images[i]+"' alt='' />");
        }
```

This of course changes the images so fast that the human eye only sees one image being in the div at all times. I want to keep each image for 3 seconds before the next .html() is done on the div. How to do this?

Comment: what JCOC611 said, you should consider changing the src attribute of am IMG element rather than injecting new one into the DOM each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to loop. If not, comment and I'll rewrite.

```
<script>
var images = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'];
var curimage = 0;
function changeImage() {
    $('#slideShow').html("<img src='../"+images[curimage]+"' alt='' />");
    curimage++;
    if (curimage > images.length) curimage = 0;
}
changeImage();
window.setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
</script>
```

I have tested this answer.

Comment: A little shorter/cleaner way of resetting `curimage` to `0` would be to use the modulus operator: `curimage = ++curimage % images.length`

Comment: @patrick dw: +1 Great point; I like your way better; however, it may be harder for the inexperienced to understand, so for now I'll leave as is....

Comment: Understood. That's always an important consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
images = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpg"];

function change(i){
   if(!images[i]){return false}
   else{
     $("#slideShow").src=images[i];
     setTimeout( function(){ change(i+1) }, 3000);
   }
}
change(0);
```

Haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: should wrap the variable i after array length

Comment: Your reference to the `arguments` object will be that of the function passed to the `setTimeout` instead of that of the `change` function. Why not just do `change(i+1)`?